# C# Action lambda limitation

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, lambda

Why does this lambda expression not compile?

```
Action a = () => throw new InvalidOperationException();
```

Conjecture is fine, but I would really appreciate references to the C# language specification or other documentation.

And yes, I know that the following is valid and will compile:

```
Action a = () => { throw new InvalidOperationException(); };
```

The context where I would use something like this is described on [this blog post](http://jacobcarpenter.wordpress.com/2008/10/06/c-compiler-eccentricity-of-the-day-throwing-lambda/).

Comment: oh, there goes the chance of getting an accepted answer :) Break out the big guns (Mr Skeet) why dont ya! :) :)

Comment: LOL. Believe me, I'm nothing special. And browsing the C# spec on a 7" screen isn't easy, either ;)

Comment: Now [compiles with C# 7.0](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44687456/11683).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hmm. I've got an answer, but it's not great.

I don't believe that there's a "throw" *expression*. There's a throw *statement*, but not just an expression. Compare this with "Console.WriteLine()" which is a method invocation expression with a void type.

As a parallel, you can't have a switch statement, or an if statement etc as the body of a lambda on its own. You can only have an expression or a block (section 7.14).

Is that any help?

Comment: That's what I said a few minutes back. You just need to ask yourself: "What does a statement evaluate to?" the answer being nothing.

Comment: Well, a call to Console.WriteLine doesn't evaluate to anything either, unless you count "void"... but yes, we were certainly thinking along the same lines, hence my +1 of your answer :)

Comment: That is helpful. I still wonder though why assignment to a closure works, since I read "num = 0" as a statement.

Comment: Console.WriteLine does match the return type though :)

Comment: "num = 0" is an assignment expression. "num=0;" is a statement.

Answer (score 15):

Here's my take:

`throw` is a statement, not an expression.

And the reference:

> 12.3.3.11 Throw statements
>
> For a statement stmt of the form
>
> `throw expr;`
>
> the definite assignment state of v
>   at the beginning of expr is the same
>   as the definite assignment state of v
>   at the beginning of stmt.

To explain the essence perhaps one should think about what an expression implies within the C# lambda construct. It is simply syntactic sugar for:

```
delegate () { return XXX; }
```

where `XXX` is an expression

Comment: But you can't ever say return Console.WriteLine("something")

Answer (score 1):

All the references I can find, from here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364047(VS.80).aspx#cs3spec_topic4

show that you have two options:

```
Action a = () => { throw new InvalidOperationException(); };
```

or

```
Action a = () => throw new InvalidOperationException()
```

Note the missing ; on the end. Yes, it makes no sense to me either. The examples they give  in the spec are:

```
x => x + 1                     // Implicitly typed, expression body
x => { return x + 1; }         // Implicitly typed, statement body
(int x) => x + 1               // Explicitly typed, expression body
(int x) => { return x + 1; }   // Explicitly typed, statement body
(x, y) => x * y               // Multiple parameters
() => Console.WriteLine()      // No parameters
```

Dunno how much help that is - I can't tell what context you are using it in, and not putting a ; on the end makes no sense in C#

the difference may be that it's an expression body - not a statement - if it doesn't have the {}. Which means that your throw is not valid there, as it's a statement, not an expression!

Comment: The no semicolon makes sense in the context of the lambda body, but not as a statement where you are assigning to an Action.

The context I would use this in is alluded to in http://jacobcarpenter.wordpress.com/2008/10/06/c-compiler-eccentricity-of-the-day-throwing-lambda/

Comment: I can guarantee you that Action a = () => throw new InvalidOperationException() does NOT compile.

Comment: The compiler still expects a ; at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

You can't return or throw from an un-scoped lambda.

Think of it this way... If you don't provide a {}, the compiler determines what your implicit return value is.  When you `throw` from within the lambda, there is no return value.  You're not even returning `void`.  Why the compiler team didn't handle this situation, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Not a big surprise. Lambda expressions are an aspect of *functional* programming. Exceptions are an aspect of *procedural* programming. The C# mesh between the two styles of programming isn't perfect.

Comment: No, it's not the side-effect aspect which is the problem here. You can't have an "if" statement even if it doesn't have side-effects, but you *can* have an assignment expression which is a side-effect. It's a statement/expression distinction.

Comment: Right. In pure functional programming, which is sort of the model which lambda expressions is going for, there are only expressions, no statements (statements are mimicked with monadic expressions). It's a a little tricky to get a statement-based language to play well with pure expressions.